# Analysis of Simon's Algorithm: Probability Expression for Matching Queries

Tags: algorithm-analysis, probability-theory, lower-bounds

> The Simon's problem is that, given a function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ such that, for all $x,y\{0,1\}^n$ t satisfies
> $$
> f(x)=f(y)\text{ iff }x=y\oplus s
> $$
> where $s\in \{0,1\}^n$, and the Simon's problem is to find the secret string $s$ by querying $f$ as few as possible. Or in other words whether the function $f$ is one-to-one ($s=0^n$) or two-to-one ($s\ne 0^n$).

While obtaining the bound for the algorithm, it is stated that, if we have queried $j−1$ times and found no matching the probability that we obtain a good matching in the $j^{th}$ query
$$
\frac{j-1}{2^n-1-{{j-1}\choose{2}}}
$$

**Note:** Please see page $2$ of [PDF 1](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse599d/06wi/lecturenotes8.pdf) or [PDF 2](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecleve/courses/F11CS667/SimonClassicalLB.pdf) for the reference.

How do we reach this expression ?

I'm trying to understand how this expression is derived. My intuition suggests that the probability of obtaining a matching result in the $j^{th}$ query after $j−1$ non-matching results is $\dfrac{j-1}{2^n-(j-1)}$.

Comment: Some context seems missing.  What are you reading?  Please provide a full reference, e.g., title, author, and section/chapter number, or where it was published.  What do you mean by "the bound for the algorithm"?  What bound?  When you say "it is stated that", who stated that?  Are you referring to a classical algorithm or a quantum algorithm?  What do you mean by a "matching"?  Please [edit] the post to clarify what you are asking.